# How can time complexity be worst on nested loop solution than one with cache?

Tags: javascript, performance, big-o

I was solving an exercise on leetCode and I offered two solutions. The exercise says this:
You're given strings J representing the types of stones that are jewels, and S representing the stones you have.  Each character in S is a type of stone you have.  You want to know how many of the stones you have are also jewels.

The letters in J are guaranteed distinct, and all characters in J and S are letters. Letters are case sensitive, so "a" is considered a different type of stone from "A".
https://leetcode.com/problems/jewels-and-stones/

So I gave these two solutions:

```
const numJewelsInStones = function(J, S) {
let counter = 0;
let jArr = J.split('');
let sArr = S.split('');

for(let i = 0; i < jArr.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < sArr.length; j++) {
        if(jArr[i] === sArr[j]) {
            counter++; }
    }
}

return counter;
```

};```

and this one with two different loops that should be O(n):

```
  const numJewelsInStones = function(J, S) {
  let counter = 0;
  let cache = {};

  for(let i = 0; i < J.length; i++) {
    cache[J[i]] = true;
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < S.length; i++) {
    if(cache[S[i]]) {
      console.log(S[i])
      counter++
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

According to leetCode the first solution takes 44ms and the second one 80ms. How can this be?

Comment: Your second solution, the slower one, has a console.log that isn't in the first. What's the performance when you comment logging out?

Comment: 1. Get rid of the console.log in the second example, that's likely to slow it down. 2. Big-O notation gives the asymptotical runtime (i.e. what it tends towards for big n, ignoring constant factors). For *practical* examples a "more optimal" algorithm can still be slower than a naive one (Example: naive string search is often faster than KMP, because of brute-forcing the naive search is still faster then creating the lookup tables).

Comment: Well, for A(n) = a * n and B(n) = b * n², B(n) > A(n) is definetly possible. It's just that there always exists an n so that B(n¹) < A(n¹) for n¹ > n. Or in other words: For large strings, your second solution will somewhen outperform the first.

Comment: Right, when I take the console.log out the runtime goes down to 62ms. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J is at most 52 characters (all the letters).

So we are dealing with small numbers and O() notation isn't so helpful...  O(s*j) <= O(52s)!

In the second case the time to build your cache is also not going to be consistent depending if it needs resizing and why do you assume lookup is O(n)?  Just be cause your loop is simple doesn't mean the things it calls are.

But runtime will be really dependent on the input in any case.

I would rewrite considering that s may be much larger than j and that you can bail out of the loop after printing.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, big O doesn't matter in small data sets. I assumed O(n) because the loops are always calling a string

Comment: Accept the answer and it will improve your reputation. :)

Comment: Tx! I get lost here